# Sumo with Unity - Generate osm file of 3d model

Tags: unity

I am working on **[SUMO](https://www.eclipse.org/sumo/) with unity** using this [open-source project](https://github.com/DarraghMac97/Real-time-Traffic-Simulation-with-3D-Visualisation). But stuck in a problem:
The background is, we need an open-street-map compatible 3D model in unity. I mean the model should be the same as the open-street-map. Sumo generates road network according to osm file. Therefore the traffic simulation properly sync in both applications (Sumo software and in unity). But my problem is I have a changed model. The model is not 100% according to OSM file or it doesn't match 100% road structure of the osm file. The reason is we have modeled slightly upgraded structure.

Is there any way that I easily edit my OSM file according to my model or vice-versa? Or I create an osm file of my 3d environment? So that it can properly sync with simulation?

Comment: If I had the intention to modify the original OSM data in SUMO, then my approach would be to try to import the files from SUMO into Unity. I just learned that this software exists, so I have no idea how feasible that is. But it's open source. Have you looked at its safe format and how difficult it would be to create an importer for Unity for it?

Comment: Sorry philipp i am clueless about your comment! Do you want to export the simulation directly from the SUMO? I think it is not imported it makes connection with SUMO.

Comment: Well, and I am clueless about Sumo. It's a very niche tool, after all. So you are saying that it has some API which allows it to communicate with Unity in real-time? Does that API allow (or could be extended) to also send map data to Unity?

Answer (score 0):

The project you use imports the same OSM data once into SUMO and once into ESRI city engine. So the easiest way to get the same network is to modify the OSM input data either directly in OpenStreetMap which you might prefer if they reflect changes in reality which you want to give back to the community or by using JOSM or a similar local (offline) OSM editor. There is currently no known way (at least to me) to convert a SUMO network back to OSM.